# Finding the longest string and its length using Java streams

Tags: java, stream

Java 8 streams are my new golden hammer that I try to use as often as possible with often enormous gains in brevity and readability. Getting multiple return values, such as a maximum value and its associated element, is a bit cumbersome though (and requires an additional "pair" class).

Should I go back to "normal Java" for this task or is this syntax preferable? Is there a more concise way?

```
List<String> names = Arrays.asList("John","Paul","Ringo"); 
Pair<String,Integer> longestName = names.stream()
 .map(n->new Pair<>(n,n.length())) // pretend n.length() to be a lengthy operation
 .max(Comparator.comparing(Pair::getB)).get();
System.out.println(longestName.getA()+" "+longestName.getB());
```

P.S.: With "lengthy operation" I mean long running, as in I don't want to calculate it twice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your concept is fine. My only criticism is in code style, and perhaps you should have a specific/custom container instead of the Pair. `getA()` and `getB()` should be `getName()` and `getLength()`. This also allows you to use primitive values and not Integer, and removes the confusing generic types.

Also:

- don't get from Optionals at the stream end.
- use white-space, it's your friend.
- use meaningful names for lambda parameters (`name` is better than `n` )

The code I would write would look like:

```
Optional<Operation> maxOp = names.stream()
                  .map (name -> new Operation(name, name.length()))
                  .max (Comparator.comparingInt(Operation::getLength()));
Operation longest = maxOp.get();

System.out.println(longest.getName() + " " + longest.getLength());
```

Comment: Sorry for the late accept and thanks for the improvement!

Answer (score 19):

You don't need the Pair.  You can get the String with the maximum length by doing

```
names.stream().max(Comparator.comparingInt(String::length))
```

Comment: Agreed. Unlike C strings, where `strlen()` is O(_n_), `String::length` should be fast.

Comment: Maybe I didn't explain the problem correctly. I want to return *both* the length and the string itself, so I want to have two return values. In this example, String::length is fast but this is just a stand in for a long running function.

Comment: @KonradHöffner this simple syntax gives you the longest string. Just get its length.

Comment: This should be the selected answer.